# Report back the error in the function defined

Tags: c++

the function is not erasing the node as required.please inform me about the error. ihave used c++ link list STL.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<iterator>

using namespace std;


void deletefriend(list <int> popularity){
    int del=0;
    list <int> :: iterator it;

    for(it=popularity.begin();it!=popularity.end();++it){
        int temp=*it;
        if(temp<*(++it)){
            --it;
            popularity.erase(it);
            del = 1;
            break;
        }
        --it;
    }
    if(del==0){
        popularity.pop_back();
    }
}

void showlist(list <int> popularity){
    list <int> :: iterator it;
    for(it=popularity.begin();it!=popularity.end();it++){
        cout<<*it<<' ';
    }
}
int main(){
    long long int T,N,K,h,i;
    cin>>T;

    while(T!=0){
        cin>>N>>K;
        list <int> popularity;
        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            cin>>h;
            popularity.push_back(h);
        }

        long long int m=0;
        while(m!=K){
            deletefriend(popularity);
            m++;
        }
        showlist(popularity);
        T--;
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input

3

3 1

3 100 1

5 2

19 12 3 4 17

5 3

23 45 11 77 18

Your Code's Output

3 100 1

19 12 3 4 17

23 45 11 77 18

Expected Correct Output

100 1

19 12 17

77 18

Comment: i have posted my complete code with example input please see through it.

Comment: You're passing the list by value to `deletefriend` so it is working on a copy of the original list. It needs to be passed by reference if you want the changes to be applied to the list passed into the function. https://ideone.com/uo5RIU